# How to make website searchable for different search engines

Tags: html, seo, search-engine

I want to create a website where people can create events related to education, entertainment, sports, regional, cultural etc. Every user will have its own page which will be publicly available. Now I want to make sure that these events are searchable by all the search engines such as Google, Bing etc, as soon as the event is created. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special you need to do to make your website crawlable, as long as your text is in html, and not generated by javascript exclusively and can be found on an url search engines will find it.

With that said if you want to speed up the indexing process you can programmatically ping google for every new content entry you make.

eg ping google:

```
http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=URLOFSITEMAP.xml
```

to ping bing:

```
http://www.bing.com/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap=http://www.yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml
```

Most search engines have an option for pinging similar to this. Keep in mind that yahoo and bing use the same technology, so you only need to ping bing.

You also need to populate your XML sitemap everytime you create new content and then automatically ping it using the url above. This will make sure that all your content is indexed as fast as possible.

Comment: How do you ping?

Comment: Request the ping URL with a script from your server

Answer (score 1):

Important SEO Techniques to follow:

```
#1 – Optimize your title tags
#2 – Create compelling meta descriptions. Make sure that words used in meta tag descriptions should be reused in a page content.
#3 – Utilize keyword-rich headings
#4 – Add ALT tags to your images.
#5 – Create a sitemap
#6 – Build internal links between pages
#7 – Update your site regularly
#8 - Provide Accessibility for all users.
```

Comment: I would add #3.1 add compelling content (not just a few lines of text and a couple of images). Search engines use the page content more and more for rankings.

Answer (score -2):

1. high-powered link building campaigns
2. always require that good old optimized content
3. Optimize your `head` section within HTML, Use a unique and relevant title and meta description on every page
4. title description for `a` tags
5. Alt text for `IMG` tags
6. use proper `H1, H2,...H6` tags
7. Use keywords in your URLs and file names,
8. Use your keywords as anchor text when linking internally.
9. Social network marketing can also help, Use press releases wisely.
10. Start a blog and participate with other related blogs.
11. Do keyword research at the start of the project.(good free tool is **Google’s AdWords** Keyword Tool, which doesn’t show exact numbers. so you may use paid versions of **Keyword Discovery** or **WordTracker**)

SEO isn’t a one-time event. Search engine algorithms change regularly, so the tactics that worked last year may not work this year. SEO requires a long-term outlook and commitment.

For more help refer:

really nice article: 
 
[12 steps for better SEO](http://www.wikihow.com/Optimize-Your-Website-for-Search-Engine-Use)
[21 Tips for SEO](http://searchengineland.com/21-essential-seo-tips-techniques-11580)

Answer (score -2):

Jump start with below links:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35291?hl=en

http://www.bing.com/toolbox/seo-analyzer

gud luck :)